# On Android 13, Bluetooth headset buttons Next/Previous or FF/Reverse don't work when playback paused

Tags: android, bluetooth, media-buttons

In my own app on Android 13 (Pixel 6 Pro), that is similar to media players, the Play/Pause button from the Bluetooth headsets works normally, but recently I noticed, that the Next/Previous buttons, or FF/Reverse, don't work when playback is paused. They work normally when playback is on. They used to work also when paused on older devices.

I decided to test this in another media playing app (YouTube) and with 2 different Bluetooth headsets - the problem is the same. YouTube also will jump e.g. to the next video when playback is on, but does not react when playback is paused.

Is this a system change in Android 13, or a bug? Can it be somehow remedied either with system settings or with the change in my app code?